# Scheduling Start Date

Tags: designer-workflow, approval-process

I have an OOTB publishing workflow on a Pages Library and I am getting issue on scheduling start date.

When I put future date and time for `Scheduling start date` and completes the workflow, it immediately start appearing to visitors with changes. At this time I see that `Approval Status` of the item is `Scheduled`. This is weird.

I think until the approval status changes to `Approved`, the pages (Items) should not appear to the visitors.

Do I need to change some condition in Publishing Workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to 
Pages Library

- Library settings
- Versioning settings

Under *Draft Item Security* see if *Only users who can edit items* is checked